# htaccess - Rewrite not allowing Escaped Characters in URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, hash

We have a file here:

```
hiddendirectory/directory/file.mp3
```

And we don't want people to see the actual directory location of the first directory, so we put this in htaccess to "hide" it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^fakedirectory/(.*)/(.*).mp3$ hiddendirectory/$1/$2.mp3 [NC,L]
```

Which allows us to use this instead in our html:

```
fakedirectory/directory/file.mp3
```

And that all works great, except sometimes it breaks if the filename has an "#" symbol or similar. So for example this results in a 404:

```
fakedirectory/directory/file#1.mp3
```

I've tried replacing the `#` with `%23` but it still doesn't work. Putting in the `%23` DOES work if I bypass htaccess and use the actual original directory name like this:

```
hiddendirectory/directory/file%231.mp3
```

But ultimately we need it to work with the fake directory we put in htaccess, like this:

```
fakedirectory/directory/file%231.mp3
```

I'm guess something in htaccess needs to be adjusted to be able to handle escaped characters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Apparently simply adding "B" to the bracket does the trick

```
RewriteRule ^fakedirectory/(.*)/(.*).mp3$ hiddendirectory/$1/$2.mp3 [B,NC,L]
```